# How to Design a Database Schema in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, data-modeling, database-schema, social-networking

I am Newbie working on a social networking site & using MongoDB as Database. Can you please assist me in What approach should I follow in Designing Database?

**My Requirements and Objective for Designing Database**

The Most common queries are gonna be related to the user interactions like what topics had user followed, how the user interacted with the post, how many times was the post on the newsfeed of the user and at what time for further showing him that post after some time.
My objective is not to calculate Number of likes, number of comments often but what they query I want to get quickly to keep the performance up is just that Is the user interested in the post by checking did he liked it or not.
So should I:

1. Make Different collections for storing likes, comments, etc containing the reference field of Posts collection & User Collection for the user who interacted.
   Ex:

   ```
   db.like.find()
   {_id: , user_id: "the user_id of the user", post_id: [ALL THE POST_ID's USER LIKED]}
   db.comment.find()
   {_id: , user_id: "the user_id of the user", comments: [{_id: , post_id: , replied_to: [ LIST OF USERS REPLIED IN THE COMMENT], votes: [ LIST OF ALL THE VOTERS] , timestamp: }] }
   ```
2. Making a List of Embedded Documents in a collection with a user_id, post_id, and any interaction he made with the post.
   So one document per user. And one embedded document in the list per post interaction.
   Ex:

   ```
   db.all_the_interactions.find()
   {_id: , user: ObjectId("1782..."), username: "Mark Alberto" interactions:[
   {post_id: ObjectId("222..."), liked: True, "Comment": ["Hello"], timestamp},
   {post_id: ObjectId("672..."), liked: False, "Comment": [], timestamp}
   ]}

   {_id: , user: ObjectId("4355..."), username: "Himesh Reshamiya" interactions:[
   {post_id: ObjectId("224..."), liked: True, "Comment": [], timestamp},
   {post_id: ObjectId("562..."), liked: False, "Comment": ["Nice"], timestamp}
   ]}
   ```
3. Making an Entire Collection for a user where all his interactions will be stored.{_id, post_id, liked(if he liked), (list of comments that this particular user made(if any)), time of comment(if any comment made)}.
   Ex:

   ```
   db.user_name.find()
   {_id, post_id: 432.., liked: True, Comment: ['StackOverflow']}
   {_id, post_id: 433.., liked: True, Comment: []}
   ```
4. Storing all the users who liked the post in the list in the posts-collection itself & a list of embedded documents for comments.
   Ex:

   ```
   db.post.find()
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f7930758bcf38e4f920e87"),
    "username" : "Akshat Bafna",
    "fact" : "clone()\r\nCreate a copy of the current queryset.clone()\r\nCreate a copy of the current queryset.",
    "background" : "mongodb-logo-vector-2022.png",
    "creation_date_time" : "08/13/2022, 17:33:19",
    "topic": "MongoDB",
    "liked":[ALL THE USER_ID's LIKED THIS POST],
    "comments":[{_id: , user_id: ,"replied_to": [ LIST OF USERS REPLIED IN THE COMMENT], votes: [ LIST OF ALL THE VOTERS] , timestamp: } ]
    }
   ```
5. Store all the Posts user liked in user collection as a list of posts_id

   ```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("62dee9d49974d78430d99af6"), 
   "user_type" : "initiatives", 
   "username" : "Anand Mahindra", 
   "password" : "99fb2f48c6af4761f904fc85f967445665445d40b1f44ec3a9c1fa319", "email" : 
   "mahindraanand@gmail.co", 
   "last_login" : "N/A", 
   "last_logout" : "N/A", 
   "post_liked": [ALL THE POST_ID's USER LIKED],
   "comments": [{_id: , post_id: ,"replied_to": [ LIST OF USERS REPLIED IN THE COMMENT], votes: [ LIST OF ALL THE VOTERS] , timestamp: }] }
   ```

As MongoDB is a Dynamic Database what should be the right criteria for designing a database for best performance?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to design a schema for that purpose will be using the combination of second and third method if you require all the data that's going to be stored in a document. The document will look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6323c511a78cf05ddc91d868"), "userReference" : ObjectId("62c1f108449a868937fgg355"), "username" : "Akshat Bafna", "postId" : ObjectId("62f563ed918ea74846d3aa95"), "liked" : false, "lighten" : false, "timesViewed" : 1, "points" : 10, "timeList" : [ "16/09/2022 06:06:33" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6323c511a78cf05ddc91d869"), "userReference" : ObjectId("62c1f108449a868937edfs7f"), "username" : "Joe Bidden", "postId" : ObjectId("62f7785eb90971094fffe9d8"), "liked" : false, "lighten" : false, "timesViewed" : 1, "points" : 10, "timeList" : [ "16/09/2022 06:06:33" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6323c511a78cf05ddc91d86a"), "userReference" : ObjectId("62c1f108449a868937fgg355"), "username" : "Akshat Bafna", "postId" : ObjectId("62f7911c4191afb7b90641d6"), "liked" : false, "lighten" : false, "timesViewed" : 1, "points" : 10, "timeList" : [ "16/09/2022 06:06:33" ] }
```

**Inshort Why I prefer this?**

1. Because ever growing arrays with embedded documents will be a       performance issue.
2. Expensive writes & updates.
3. Document size limit on 16mb in mongodb as ever-growing documents    becoz of ever growing arrays will never stop it will be an issue.
4. Index creation will get expensive.

For more information, see: [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?.](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/)

Also you might have to add some data redundancy for better performance, create ttl indexes with the single user_interactions collection or when using a separate collection for individual user capped collections can be used if it does not violate your requirements.